Using Swift backup proper without loosing data
As you know the most popular app in root users was originally titanium backup but as you know that titanium backup cannot backup split apks not work properly, as I found a new app and if you are a root user you might be familiar with Swift backup
I seriously think this is a very good app. for backing up and app completely.
but the problem comes in copying the folder of Swift backup.
Sometimes you have to loose data because of improper copying of the folder Swift backup .
Can you help me provide a solution for it

Swift backup is a commercial software, may be you contact their support if you have problems with the app. Note that even on a rooted device cryptographic keys stored in the hardware backed AndoridKeyStore can not be extracted as the keys will never leave their hardware protected environment.

Yeah you are right , but it can at least backup and recover WhatsApp and many other apps like that and I think that it is somewhat better than titanium backup as it crashes on Android 10 + and cannot recover split apks
